# Can we use phonegap javascript library with a regular internet site?

Tags: javascript, cordova

If i develope a **regular** Website using the phongap.js library, Will it still works on mobiles
(with access to goelocation,media,device,events etc...) **Without** turning it into an application?

(without using the SDKs or phonegap build)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, no. The PhoneGap library must be compiled, something which is not offered via web applications served directly from urls.

You'll often find whilst debugging an error we have been fighting with for quite sometime, which is "com is not defined."

Answer (score 3):

No, phonegap.js has hooks to the native systems. It has to have the native objective-c and Java files in order to work and access those features.

You can however use HTML5 geolocation for geo, but other than that you're very limited.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.  Phonegap API's only interface with phones and mobile devices when running within a wrapper which provides those extra features.  The JavaScript calls can not function without the platform-specific libraries there to support them.

Further reading:

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/cde8e4735dd6da9d
http://paulparisi.com.au/2011/09/26/adventures-in-reverse-engineering-a-phonegap-app/